# SQL Problem regarding to get the sum of duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my sql query to get the following table below :

```
select c.name, s.company, p.qty, p.qty * p.price as Total
from client c, purchase p, stock s
where c.clno = p.clno AND s.company = p.company
group by c.name, s.company, p.qty, p.qty * p.price
order by sum(p.qty) desc
```

The output of the above query looks like this :

```
Name  |  Company  |  Qty  |  Total
John      ABC         12       100
Bob       XYZ         10       150
John      ABC          5        50
Bob       XYZ         20       250
Bob       XYZ          2        20
Nav       QRS         10       150
John      ABC         10       150
```

I want to have the query to get the output as the following :

```
Name  |  Company  |  Qty  |  Total
John      ABC         27       300
Bob       XYZ         32       420
Nav       QRS         10       150
```

Answer (score 1):

As of now your query uses `GROUP BY` but does not actually aggregates data. You want to `GROUP BY` name and company, and `SUM` the quantities and amounts, like :

```
select c.name, s.company, SUM(p.qty), SUM(p.qty * p.price) as Total
from client c
inner join purchase p on c.clno = p.clno
inner join stock s on s.company = p.company
group by c.name, s.company
order by Total desc
```

Other remarks regarding your query :

- always use explicit joins instead of implicit ones
- you can use column aliases in the `ORDER BY` clause (here, `Total` ; this can make the query easier to read